# SMTP ASP.NET Winsock Connectivity

Tags: asp.net, smtp, winsock

ASP.Net 1.1, 2.0 and 4.0 cannot send emails. But when I use classic ASP it can send emails.
Telnet can also send emails.

Windows Server Standard (2007)

I receive this error:

The message could not be sent to the SMTP server. The transport error code was 0x800ccc14. The server response was not available

I know this is a winsock issue and this issue happens once in a while and we perform a reboot and everything is okay.

What I want to know is what causes this and can I prevent this or stop rebooting every single time?

Added this to my blog : http://www.moushigo.com/index.php/2012/02/22/trivial-smtp-asp-net-winsock-connectivity-issues/

Comment: Have you checked System.Net.Mail? It is available since .Net 2.0

Comment: Yes, I think it is the only solution to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few weeks of debugging and fix finding the only workaround for this would be to either reboot the server or move to using System.Net.Mail.